# Портфолио для FCC

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/PmaqQr

При верстке столкнулся с такой проблемой, футер почему-то уходит наверх, прошелся по div'ам, вроде все закрыты, не понимаю с чем это связано и как исправить эту проблему.
Благодарен за любую помощь!

Прикрепляю полную разметку, CSS и HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

 :active,
 :hover,
 :focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

 ::selection {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

 ::-moz-selection {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

h3.main {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.250em;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}

h1.main {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #eee;
  left: 5%;
  line-height: 0.5;
  padding-top: 25%;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.header {
  background: url('../img/header.png');
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  /* Opera 9.6+ */
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Современные браузеры */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

.fa-bars {
  position: relative;
  color: #eee;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 150%;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
  color: #999;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-long-arrow-up {
  color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 0.35s
}

.fa-long-arrow-up:hover {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

p.main {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.000em;
  color: #404040;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #626060;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 72.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

p.text {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  right: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-heart-o {
  border: 5px solid #242424;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-heart-o:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-toggle-on:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

p.onblock {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.313em;
  color: #404040;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  right: 32.5%
}

.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.horizontal2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.galleryphoto:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) blur(0px);
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.galleryphoto {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: 0.35s;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.margin {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.margin2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 17.5%;
}

h4.comments {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  color: #676666;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #676666;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-smile-o {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 17px;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  transition: 0.35s;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-smile-o:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-paper-plane {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 17px;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  transition: 0.35s;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-paper-plane:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

textarea {
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  left: 3%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 53px;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888585;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  color: #404040;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.commentfont {
  position: relative;
  color: #249cce;
  font-size: 1.575em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.date {
  position: relative;
  color: #a4a4a4;
  font-size: 1.005em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 6%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.comment {
  position: relative;
  color: #676666;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  left: 5%;
}

.vmore {
  border: 1px solid #575757;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
  left: 40%;
  position: relative;
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.vmore:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
  color: #249cce;
}

.main2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.000em;
  color: #404040;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7%;
  left: 4%;
}

.fa-vk {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  transition: 0.35s;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-vk:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-twitter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-github {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-github:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-envelope {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-envelope:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tvarinsky Klondike</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=450, initial-scale=1" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-9">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5 col-md-offset-4">
          <h1 class="main">TVARINSKY</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
          <h3 class="main">Front-end разработчик <br>UI/UX дизайнер</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-flip-vertical fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main">Обо мне</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text">Здравствуйте! Я Иван.<br> Я Front-end разработчик,<br> UI/UX дизайнер.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Моя жизнь</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Это работает</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Всё как у людей</p>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main">Портфолио</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text">Ниже представлены<br> выполненные мною работы.<br> Вы можете оценить их.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
        <img src="img\portfolio\2.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\3.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\4.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-3">
        <img src="img\portfolio\1.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\8.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
        <img src="img\portfolio\7.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\6.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\5.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main margin2">Отзывы</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line margin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text margin">Здесь Вы можете оставить
        <BR> отзыв о моей работе,
        <BR> предложение, пожелание.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="horizontal2"></div>
      <h4 class="comments">Комментарии (2)</h4>
      <br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Введите текст сообщения..." maxlength="300" wrap="hard"></textarea>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

      <!-- Первый комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Екатерина</p>
      <p class="date">2017.02.11 18:33</p>
      <p class="comment">Отличная работа, Иван! Выполнил всё даже раньше обговоренных сроков,<br> помог с настройкой таблиц MySQL, сверстал, отличный адаптивный веб-сайт!</p>
      <!-- Первый комментарий -->

      <!-- Второй комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Никита</p>
      <p class="date">2016.11.07 21:40</p>
      <p class="comment">Иван отличный специалист, сделал все быстро и качественно. P.S. Дополнительно был реализован функционал
        <BR>который изначально не обсуждали, но при этом исполнитель все сделал и не требовал доп оплаты. Рекомендую!
      </p>
      <!-- Второй комментарий -->

      <!-- Показать еще -->
      <a href="#" class="vmore">Показать еще</a>
      <!-- Показать еще -->

      <div class="horizontal2"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
        <p class="main2">Контактная информация</p>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-3">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ссылку на живую страницу, как на Вашей картинке. А то через по приведенному коду верстка отображается очень криво, по крайней мере у меня.

Comment: @СветланаПавлова Она отображается очень криво из-за того, что здесь нет бутстрапа, сейчас залью на codepen

Comment: @СветланаПавлова - https://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/PmaqQr

Пикчи и FA не загрузил, но суть видна

Comment: Хорошо! Ответила в поле "ответ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидела. Оберните в div с классом row все, что находится в div'е с классом content (21 строка) и заканчивается перед футером. Тогда футер опустится.
Вот https://codepen.io/Svetlana_J/pen/OmENZK

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-9">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5 col-md-offset-4">
          <h1 class="main">TVARINSKY</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
          <h3 class="main">Front-end разработчик <br>UI/UX дизайнер</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-flip-vertical fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main">Обо мне</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text">Здравствуйте! Я Иван.<br> Я Front-end разработчик,<br> UI/UX дизайнер.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Моя жизнь</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Это работает</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Всё как у людей</p>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main">Портфолио</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text">Ниже представлены<br> выполненные мною работы.<br> Вы можете оценить их.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
        <img src="img\portfolio\2.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\3.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\4.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-3">
        <img src="img\portfolio\1.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\8.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
        <img src="img\portfolio\7.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\6.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\5.png" class="galleryphoto" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
      <p class="main margin2">Отзывы</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="line margin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <p class="text margin">Здесь Вы можете оставить
        <BR> отзыв о моей работе,
        <BR> предложение, пожелание.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="horizontal2"></div>
      <h4 class="comments">Комментарии (2)</h4>
      <br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Введите текст сообщения..." maxlength="300" wrap="hard"></textarea>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

      <!-- Первый комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Екатерина</p>
      <p class="date">2017.02.11 18:33</p>
      <p class="comment">Отличная работа, Иван! Выполнил всё даже раньше обговоренных сроков,<br> помог с настройкой таблиц MySQL, сверстал, отличный адаптивный веб-сайт!</p>
      <!-- Первый комментарий -->

      <!-- Второй комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Никита</p>
      <p class="date">2016.11.07 21:40</p>
      <p class="comment">Иван отличный специалист, сделал все быстро и качественно. P.S. Дополнительно был реализован функционал
        <BR>который изначально не обсуждали, но при этом исполнитель все сделал и не требовал доп оплаты. Рекомендую!
      </p>
      <!-- Второй комментарий -->

      <!-- Показать еще -->
      <a href="#" class="vmore">Показать еще</a>
      <!-- Показать еще -->

      <div class="horizontal2"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
        <p class="main2">Контактная информация</p>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-3">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>

  </div>
```